# HTML5 boilerplate Why am i getting so many css errors

Tags: modernizr, html5boilerplate

I have just installed HTML5 boilerplate and have not added any markup to the index.html file yet I'm already getting all kids of css errors including, but not limited to the following:

Expected media feature name but found 'transform-3d'.

Expected media feature name but found '-webkit-transform-3d'

Expected media feature name but found '-o-transform-3d'

Expected media feature name but found '-ms-transform-3d'

Expected media feature name but found 'modernizr'.

Error: WebGL: Can't get a susable WebGL context

Unknown property -moz-opacity' declaratoin dropped,

The list goes on and on.... There area dozens of these.

Have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`transform-3d` is not used in HTML5 Boilerplate. This must be something different. Do you have any other styles running?

Anyway: There are a lot of errors (35) when validating the HTML5BP's CSS with the [W3C Validator](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator). Most of them are because there are some hacks for Internet Explorer 6 and 7.

Please just don't care too much about them. It doesn't do anything wrong to your page. Remove the hacks if you don't need IE6 and 7 support.

Answer (score 0):

I just uploaded a default fluid grid boilerplate.css and tried to validate it.

33 errors; and I had not edited it at all.